# can not find urdf.why?how to solve it?

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosrun urdfdom check_urdf my_robot.urdf
[rospack] Error: stack/package urdfdom not found

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114781/can-not-find-urdf.why?how-to-solve-it?/) by [peter_pan_lqm](https://answers.ros.org/users/9651/peter_pan_lqm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2014-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ha!  I just came across this a few minutes ago and see that it has already been answered in this forum elsewhere.  The short answer is that there was a ROS package change that now requires a different command line than what is shown in the tutorials.  Try the following and it should work:

```
check_urdf my_robot.urdf
```

"rosrun" and the package name are not required.

---

Originally posted by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) with karma: 159 on 2014-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1